# Changing MySQL password via WHM - does this affect WordPress?

Tags: mysql

For security, I changed the CPanel password for an account via WHM. There's a checkbox option that says "Sync MySQL password with account password."

If I go ahead and change the password, does that create a problem for WordPress that's installed on that domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, just found out that it doesn't. Here's the doc from Cpanel directly

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/RestoringDatabaseAccess

Sorry, now that I know the answer, this definitely isn't WordPress related.

Comment: I can confirm that the 'Sync MySQL password with account password' doesn't affect your WP install, I tested it on my site.

Answer (score 2):

If that changes the MySQL password that WordPress is using, and it sounds like it does, then yes you will have a problem, but not a big one. You'd need to edit `wp-config.php` and change `define('DB_PASSWORD','oldpass');` to `define('DB_PASSWORD','newpass');` Beyond that, the question is a CPanel question and would be off topic here.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Set_Database_Password

Comment: While it's Cpanel related, the main concern is WordPress and the reason I posted it here. Thanks for your response and I'll check out the config file. Cheers!